# Is there a problem in mixing @Transactional with "jpaApi.withTransaction"?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I was having some trouble making transactions work properly in my play application, and my code is structured in such a way that I cannot afford the time to do it "properly" as it shows in the Play Framework documentation.

Only using @Transactional was not enough because for some reason  it was not rolling back when I threw my own exceptions.

So this is the way I managed to make transactions work:

```
@Transactional
public Result myAction() {
    try {
        return ok(Json.toJson(myServiceClass.doStuff()));
    } catch (BusinessRuleException e) {
        return badRequest(Json.toJson("error"));
    }
}

...

public class MyServiceClass {
    public Bill doStuff() throws BusinessRuleException {
        return jpaApi.withTransaction(() -> {

               //...do a bunch of stuff here

        });
    }
}
```

Is this fine? Can it cause problems later for some reason?

Comment: Your custom exceptions extend `RuntimeException`?

Comment: Yes, they extend RuntimException. But it appears the transaction is only rolled back when I don't catch the exception, and I must be able to catch it in order to display error messages to the user.

Answer (score 0):

`@Transactional` and `JPAApi.withTransaction` under the hood creates new instances of entity managers. This entity managers serves as unit of work. In this situation you wind up with two running transactions that don't connected. So I guess it's better not mix this two approaches and choose one of them.